# Getting Spring IOC to work with the MVP pattern

Tags: java, spring, ioc-container, mvp

I'm attempting to use the [MVP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-presenter) design pattern with a Swing application in conjunction with Spring IOC. In MVP the View needs to pass itself into the Presenter, and I can't work out how to do this with Spring.

```
public class MainView  implements IMainView {

    private MainPresenter _presenter;

    public MainView() {

        _presenter = new MainPresenter(this,new MyService());

       //I want something more like this
       // _presenter = BeanFactory.GetBean(MainPresenter.class);

    }

}
```

This is my config xml (incorrect)

```xml
<bean id="MainView" class="Foo.MainView"/>
<bean id="MyService" class="Foo.MyService"/>

<bean id="MainPresenter" class="Foo.MainPresenter">
    <!--I want something like this, but this is creating a new instance of View, which is no good-->
   <constructor-arg type="IMainView">
        <ref bean="MainView"/>
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg  type="Foo.IMyService">
        <ref bean="MyService"/>
     </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

How do I get the View into the Presenter?

Comment: I don't understand... you've commented out the part of the config that injects the view into the presenter, which is what you're asking how to do... what gives?

Comment: Changed the question to make it clearer - I commented it out as its not correct.

Comment: OK, but that config isn't creating a new instance of the view, it's passing a reference to the existing `MainView` bean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override constructor arguments used for bean creation with `BeanFactory.getBean(String name, Object... args)`. The shortcomings of this way are that lookup must be done by bean name rather than by its class, and that this method overrides all constructor arguments at once, so you have to use setter dependency for `MyService`:

```
 public class MainView  implements IMainView { 

    private MainPresenter _presenter; 

    public MainView() { 
        _presenter = beanFactory.getBean("MainPresenter", this); 
    }  
}
```

Also note the `prototype` scope, it's because each `MainView` needs its own `MainPresenter`

```
<bean id="MyService" class="Foo.MyService"/>   

<bean id="MainPresenter" class="Foo.MainPresenter" scope = "prototype">   
    <constructor-arg type="IMainView"><null /></constructor-arg>   
    <property name = "myService">   
        <ref bean="MyService"/>   
    </property>   
</bean>
```